# Naturally occurring elements in other planets and their natural satellites other than earth

Tags: chemistry, periodic-table

[Naturally occurring elements](https://nutrients.ifas.ufl.edu/nutrient_pages/bsfpages/NaturalElements.htm)

Is it possible to find natural elements in other planets and their natural satellites other than planet earth?

Comment: this does not seem to be a history question

Comment: There was a story recently claiming China found  He³ on the moon, much more plentiful than on the earth.  Hypothetically, it will be useful as fuel for fusion reactors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, naturally occurring elements can possibly be found on other planets than Earth and their satellites.  In fact, those other planets and their satellites are totally composed of naturally occuring elements.  So any astronauts or space probes that take samples of those planets and satellites and anyalize them will find variouscombounds made o fnaturally occuring elements.

But all the naturally occurring elements are found on Earth in larger or smaller amounts.

Scientiists have created dozens of elements in the labatories which are not found naturally.  Those elements are too unstable to last long.  Some decay into other elements in mere fractions of a second.

Those heavy and  unstable elements may haveen created in supernovas and been present on Earth and other planets and satellites when they formed billions of years ago, but have long since decayed into other elements and can't be found naturally occuring anywhere in this solar system or in any solar system more than a tiny fraction as old as ours.

Elements which have never been created by scientists in labatories would be very hard to create by natural processes, and should be even more unstable than the ones created on Earth so far.  And thus shey should also have decayed into other more stable elements almost immediately after being created.

So, unlike in many science fiction stories, scientists think that it is almost totally impossible to ever discover new elements, never found or created on Earth, on other planets, moons, asteroids, comets, etc. in our solar system or other solar sytems, or floating in outer space.

And if you want to learn about the very, very, very small hope that there could be as yet undiscovered stable elements on other worlds, you will have ask someone more knowledgable about atomic physics.

Comment: To be clear, supernovas make plenty of weird nuclei that we will never make here on Earth. But you won’t find the exotic ones in a mature solar system since they are unstable.